# При нажатии на якорную ссылку перекидывает на главную

Tags: html, jquery

Есть сайт https://studentprograms.ru/programs/mainland/group-exam-course.html в шапке есть ссылка "Обратная связь", которая вызывает форму во всплывающем окне.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В форме есть ссылка "Я ознакомлен с условиями обработки моих персональных данных при получении услуг Компании" нажав на которую, должно во всплывающем окне появиться окно с согласием об обработке персональных данных, но когда нажимаю перекидывает на главную и уже на главной открывается это окно. Как сделать чтобы на той же странице открывалось данное окно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фиолетовое окошко должно всплывать на той же странице

Answer (score 1):

Не может одновременно открывать **два модальных окна**, при нажатии на ссылку `условиями обработки моих персональных данных` должно закрываться первое окно и запускаться второе. Что используете для мода? Если bootstrap то есть функция на jq, смотри доки. Если сам писал, с помощью стилей, то можно стилями css или так же с jq.

Comment: Как подправить? Какое условие написать? В JS не силен я. Дело в том что окно самой формы закрывать не нужно, нужно поверх нее открыть окно с соглашением

Comment: Я же написал, что  одновременно два мода не открыть.

Comment: До этого работало, кто-то другой на сайт правки какие-то видимо внес и перестало работать

Comment: Дело не в этом. На этой же странице https://studentprograms.ru/programs/mainland/group-exam-course.html ниже есть эта же форма на самой странице, если там нажать на ссылку "Я ознакомлен с условиями обработки моих персональных данных при получении услуг Компании" тоже перекидывает на главную

Comment: @Kolhoznik ну значит не модальными окнами выводилось, а простой див по ввер другого.

Comment: Пропешите вашей ссылке `https://studentprograms.ru/programs/mainland/group-exam-course.html/#win1` тогда будет открываться на главной. Но возникнет проблема с закрытием ибо ссылка на закрытие `https://studentprograms.ru/#close`.
У вас на всех страницах перед подвалом эта форма, поэтому нужно прописывать на каждой странице окончание #win1. Но проблема с закрытием не решается.

Comment: Через bootstpap сделал. Спасибо